# Git Permission Error occurs via ssh when I have multiple github accounts

Tags: git, github

I have two Github accounts, one is troy and another is yort, I've generated ssh keys for both and associated them to related Github account. BTW, `id_rsa` is the identity file for troy, and `id_rsa_yort` is for yort.

For one project of the yort account, I've already set the `user.name` and `user.email` of git local config to yort account, but it always turned an error that Permission to `yort/xxx.git` denied to troy when executing `git push`.

I've tried many ways, only if I push it via `https.git` could work. Anyone can help?

Below is the git local config list:

```
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:yort-xxx/xxx.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.feature/troy/backend.remote=origin
branch.feature/troy/backend.merge=refs/heads/feature/troy/backend
branch.feature/troy/backend_reflection.remote=origin
branch.feature/troy/backend_reflection.merge=refs/heads/feature/troy/backend_reflection
user.name=yort
user.email=yort.xxx@gmail.com
credential.helper=
```

Comment: How have you configured git and ssh to pass different keys for different accounts?

Comment: @phd Just generated different keys then added them to different accounts.

Comment: That's not enough. Without special configuration `git` will just use `ssh` which will use key `id_rsa` for all accounts.

Comment: @phd Yes, it duplicates, and my issue is solved, thank you so much!